# ConfigurationManager is not found

Tags: c#, configurationmanager

I use the ConfigurationManager in my class. I add the using System.Configuration. The using is grey and the ConfigurationManager unknown. Why my .NET Core 3.1 project don't know System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager? It should be standard?!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add **System.Configuration.dll** to the referencess. or installing corresponding package by
**Install-Package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager** command.